# kubernetes go-client: How to refresh token, using kubeconfig file

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go, kubernetes-go-client

While trying to connect to kubernetes cluster using kubeconfig file I am getting below mentioned error

`Response: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Refresh token is invalid or has already been claimed by another client."}`

Following is the sequence of instruction executed

1. create a clientset using the kubeconfig file

```
    config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", kubeconfig)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    clientset:= kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
```

2. Connect to the namespace

```
    ns, err := clientset.CoreV1().Namespaces().Get(namespace, metav1.GetOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)   ///Getting the error at this place
    }
```

3. if error, get the latest kubeconfig file
4. execute from step1

If I restart the server and try running this code, it works.
But I need a way to make it work without restarting the servers.